# Active Directory: Move users to different OUs

Tags: java, active-directory, ou

I'm develop an app that needs create and maintain users into the active directory.

My problem is that the users have a hierarchy and the master can create them with different password expiration values. I was reading about that and maybe it's possible do it using OUs , but I can't found some code example about it.

Maybe exist a better way to do the requirement, but unfortunately this is the only way that I found.

**Solution (that work for me)**

When you are creating the distinguished name (dn), you have to add the the OU into the value. This is the code that I made:

```
protected String getDN(User user)
{
  //User name
  String dn = "CN=" + user.getLogin();

  //OU
  String ou;
  if (user.getPasswordExpirationTime() == 1)
    ou = "PJ1"; //one day
  else if (usuario.getPasswordExpirationTime() == 30)
    ou = "PJ30"; //thirty days
  else if (usuario.getPasswordExpirationTime() == 60)
    ou = "PJ60"; //sixty days
  else
    ou = "PJ90"; //default, ninety days

  dn += ",OU=" + ou;

  //Domain
  dn += ",DC=domain,DC=local";

  return dn;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a example on how to do it:

```
String oldUserName = "CN=Albert Einstein,OU=Research,DC=antipodes,DC=com";
String newUserName = "CN=Albert Einstein,OU=Sales,DC=antipodes,DC=com";
// Create the initial directory context
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
// Move the user
ctx.rename(oldUserName,newUserName);
```

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1157099